# linq is taking long to order by datediff

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to convert the following sql query to linq. The sql query is taking one second to run, but the linq is taking about 10 seconds
to return the results. Could anyone please let me know how can I reduce the time on linq query

```
select datediff(mm, min(QueuedTime), max(QueuedTime)), SequencingQueue 
from tbl_AS_MessageQueue with (nolock)
group by SequencingQueue 
order by datediff(mm, min(QueuedTime), max(QueuedTime)) desc

var longRunningQueries = context.TblMessageQueues.GroupBy(x => x.SequencingQueue).Select(g => new TblMessageQueueDto
{
    DateDiff = DbFunctions.DiffMonths(g.Min(x => x.QueuedTime), 
    g.Max(x => x.QueuedTime)),
    SequencingQueue = g.Key
}).OrderByDescending(a => a.DateDiff).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you show the resulting SQL as well?

Comment: Try adding `ToList()` before the `OrderByDescending`

Comment: As well as the SQL, also look at the query plans.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your query to select DTO after ordering:

```
var longRunningQueries = context.TblMessageQueues
    .GroupBy(x => x.SequencingQueue)
    .Select(g => new {
        DateDiff = DbFunctions.DiffMonths(g.Min(x => x.QueuedTime), g.Max(x => x.QueuedTime)),
        SequencingQueue = g.Key
    }).OrderByDescending(a => a.DateDiff)
    .Select(t => new TblMessageQueueDto {
        DateDiff = t.DateDiff,
        SequencingQueue = t.SequencingQueue
    }).ToList();
```